# How can I wrap text in QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt, text, word-wrap, qgraphicsitem

1) How can I wrap text in a `QGraphicsTextItem` to fit a fixed rectangle, with width and height ?

Right now I am experimenting with creating a text, getting its bounding rectangle, and resizing it to fit the box - but I can't get wrapping.

```
class TTT: public QGraphicsTextItem {
    TTT() {
    {
        setPlainText("abcd");
        qreal x = m_itemSize.width()/boundingRect().width();
        qreal y = m_itemSize.height()/boundingRect().height();
        scale(x, y);
    }
    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget) {
        // experiment with clip regions
        // text gets covered by hole in clip
        QRegion r0(boundingRect().toRect());
        QRegion r1(QRect(5, 5, 10, 10), QRegion::Ellipse);
        QRegion r2 = r0.subtracted(r1);
        painter->setClipRegion(r2);
        painter->setBrush(Qt::yellow);
        painter->drawRect(boundingRect());
        QGraphicsTextItem::paint(painter, option, widget);
    }
}
```

What makes wrapping happen, how can I trigger it ?

Right now, as I keep typing, the box is automatically expanding.

2) Is it possible to wrap the text in a `QGraphicsItem` / `QGraphicTextItem` subclass in a shape that is not a rectangle ? 
[image]

(Something like in the image above)
I tried to use `clipRegion`, see code above, but I guess it is not the right way to go, clipping cuts the text but did not wrap.

Maybe it would... If I could figure out how to wrap text in the first place ?

Qt 4.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not specify Qt version but try:

> void QGraphicsTextItem::setTextWidth(qreal width)
>
> Sets the preferred width for the item's text. If the actual text is wider than >the specified width then it will be broken into multiple lines.
>
> If width is set to -1 then the text will not be broken into multiple lines >unless it is enforced through an explicit line break or a new paragraph.
>
> The default value is -1.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to 1) I'd opt not to use the QGraphicsTextItem, but draw the text directly in your QGraphicsItem's paint function using the [drawText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawText-14) overloaded function, which takes a [QTextOption](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextoption.html) parameter.

Using this, you can set the WrapMode, for example, with a call to

```
QTextOption::setWrapMode(QTextOption:: WordWrap)
```

As for 2) with a non-rectangular shape, I don't think Qt will do this for you.

Doing it yourself you can use [QFontMetrics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html), to work out just how much text would fit in each line, depending upon where it lies within its bounding item.

Alternatively, you could adapt the concept of a [text-to-path method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753657/how-to-write-a-text-around-a-circle-using-qpainter-class).

Comment: I have considered this option for a number of reasons, but will I not lose text editing capabilities ? I still want the text to be editable once placed on the canvas - which I can do now by controlling `setTextInteractionFlags`

Comment: Also, I have seen this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17193721/1217150) about using `QFontMetrics` and it seemed like a great idea - except I don't know how to  wrap without adding `\n` in text - which would be bad because the text could change later, either in content or in size... This is hard !

Comment: *Will I lose text editing capabilities* - in simple terms, yes. However, I'd create my own GraphicsTextItem to do the drawing and allow for editing. Or, you could, when the item is selected, display a QGraphicsTextItem ready to edit and when finished, transfer the info to your own class, which draws it as you want it to.

Comment: *This is hard* - no one said it would be easy! Rather than adding escaped end of line characters, I'd go with drawing each character separately, as is done with the [text-to-path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753657/how-to-write-a-text-around-a-circle-using-qpainter-class). This will give you the flexibility you need and you'll spend less time trying to fight where to dynamically place the /n character.

Comment: I was just considering - adding a `QGraphicsTextItem` member object inside a `QGraphicsItem` subclass perhaps.. or keep the current inheritance but draw the text inside `paint` instead of calling the `QGraphicsTextItem::paint`... Thank you for the suggestions, I have some more experiments to do now :-)

Comment: I will accept the other answer - `setTextWidth` is the literal answer to my first question - even though I may have to complicate the implementation to do _exactly_ what i want. (Though your answer gives me a lot more useful information and points me in a better direction)